# Mvc Modal Ajax Form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

My Question is similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965983/mvc-ajax-submitting-from-a-modal)

What I want to achieve is to display a dialog containing a form for a simple input. Like qty of an article, when the user hits submit, all the dialog should do is close and submit data without reloading the whole page.

This is the Partial View loaded by the form:

```
@model TRUNCATED.Models.AddToCartModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Order", new AjaxOptions { // DO I NEED ANY? }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>AddToCartModel</legend>

        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "File", new { ArticleId = Model.ArticleId })" title="Artikelbild" style="resize:both; width: 300px; height:200px;" />

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ArticleId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

This is the dialog js:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizeable: false,
    width: 350,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
    },
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$(".showDialog").on("click", function (e) {
    $('#dialog').load(this.href).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

This is how I open the dialog:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddToCart", 
new { id =item.ArticleId}, 
new { @class = "showDialog" }
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
{
    return PartialView("_AddToCart", new AddToCartModel() { ArticleId = id });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(AddToCartModel atm)
{   
    if (OrderData.CartItems.Count > 0)
        atm.Pos = OrderData.CartItems.Max(i => i.Pos) + 1;
    else 
        atm.Pos = 1;

    OrderData.CartItems.Add(atm);

    return // What goes here?
}
```

Im new to this and I have no clue what I am doing wrong here.
I Replaced the Hml. with Ajax. but this didnt change anything.

It works though, but it reloads the whole page, which has sideeffects like that a Webgrid sets back to back one and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use Ajax.BeginForm instead BeginForm and call close window function on Succcess event.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "CloseWindow()" }, new { id = "id", @class = "class" }))
{
}
```

Aditionaly if you need to add some message to user you can implement this in your POST action like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(AddToCartModel atm)
{   
    if (OrderData.CartItems.Count > 0)
        atm.Pos = OrderData.CartItems.Max(i => i.Pos) + 1;
    else 
        atm.Pos = 1;

    OrderData.CartItems.Add(atm);

    return Content("<p>ITEM ADDED TO CART</p>");//will be returned by ajax
}
```

and modify your ajax form with UpdateTargetId. Message will be appended to element woth this Id

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Paceholder to message", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "CloseWindow()" }, new { id = "form-catalog", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
}
```

Comment: Gives me an empty page saying "ITEM ADDED TO CART" meaning that data doesnt get loaded into the targetID div.

Comment: That is not ajax. Are you using Ajax form? All scripts added for this on page?

Comment: You need jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js reference on page.

Comment: I forgot to add the loading of the bundle "~/bundles/jqueryval".
I made sure its in the budnle but not that the bundle gets loaded-.-

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing a Ajax Post Request to the controller, in fact you're just loading the PartialView of the form in the dialog and when you hit Submit it is being submitted as usual.

You could either implement the `Ajax.BeginForm` or capture the click event on the submit button with jQuery and make an Ajax Post Request to the controller.

```
var values = $('#form-id').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/controller/method',
    data: values,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: values,
    success: function(result){
        // do something on success
    },
    error: function(){
        // do something on error
    }    
});
```